# Stream.Dispose or stream=null?

Tags: c#, .net

I've have some code similar to this:

```
HttpWebRequest req;
HttpWebResponse response;
Stream receiveStream = null;
StreamReader readStream = null;
try
{
    req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("someUrl"));
    req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    req.Method = "GET";

    response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.Default);

    return readStream.ReadToEnd();
}
catch
{
    return "Error";
}
finally 
{
    readStream = null;
    receiveStream = null;
    response = null;
    req = null;
}
```

Should this code have readStream.Dispose() and responseStream.Dispose() instead of setting both to null?

Comment: +1 Glad you're asking this question! Most copy-and-pasted google code ignores this.

Comment: Side note but it may not be relevant. You shouldn't have a `catch` all block. That isn't good practice. You'd want to be looking for, catching and handling specific exceptions. Otherwise you want the exception to propagate up. If you are already aware of this, forgive me.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  I'll start disposing :-)  For the record i cut the exception handling from the example so it isn't as bad as it appears although from the comments i think this is something else that can be improved. Thanks again all

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's almost always a mistake to set local variables to null, unless you want to actually use that value later on. It doesn't force garbage collection any earlier - if you're not going to read from the variable later, the garbage collector can ignore the reference (when not in debug mode).

However, it's almost always correct to close streams - ideally in a `using` statement for simplicity.

It's *also* almost always wrong to have a bare "catch" block like that. Do you really want to handle *anything* going wrong, including things like `OutOfMemoryException`?

I would rewrite your code as:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("someUrl"));
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
req.Method = "GET";

using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),
                                                  Encoding.Default))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Now if something goes wrong, the exception will be propagated to the caller. You might want to catch a few *specific* exceptions, but it's generally not a good idea to represent errors using a value which could have been a valid "normal" response.

Finally, are you really sure you want `Encoding.Default`? That's the default encoding of the *local machine* - you normally want the encoding indicated by the response itself.

Comment: There is an upside to setting local variables to null:  it alerts other developers that they need to review this person's code very carefully.

Answer (score 27):

It should have `using` [which calls `Dispose()`].

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Dispose() them.

Even better to do something like

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse() )
using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream() )
using (readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.Default) )
{
   return readStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

A `using(x) {}`  block will be rewritten (by the compiler) 
as a `try {} finally {x.Dispose();}`

Note that the WebRequest is not IDisposable.

Also note that the following lines accomplish the same thing as all of your code:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = ...;
    client.Credentials = ...;
    return client.DownloadString("SomeUrl");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  Pretty much anything that implements a Dispose() method must have its Dispose() method called.  You can implicitly call it in a with the 'using' statement:

```
using(StreamReader stream = GetStream())
{
   stream.DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: You're missing the variable name there

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

When you set to null, it only nulls the reference. It doesn't run any cleanup code the creator of the Stream class wrote.

You may also want to consider the `using(){ }` statement which handles this for you on IDisposable types.

Example:

```
using (MyDisposableObject mdo = new MyDisposableObject)
{
   // Do some stuff with mdo
   // mdo will automatically get disposed by the using clause
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you should call Dispose or Close

Answer (score 2):

Safest method:

```
try {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("someUrl");
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    request.Method = "GET";
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse()) {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default)) {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
} catch {
    return "Error";
}
```

There's no need to dispose of the `response.GetResponseStream()` stream explicitly because the attached `StreamReader` will dispose it for you.

EDIT: I agree with the other answers - catching exceptions like that is very bad practice. I just left it in for comparison purposes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you should explicitly call Dispose() on classes that implement IDisposable after you have used them - this ensures all their resources get cleaned up in a timely fashion. Wrapping the variable in a `using()` does the same thing (which adds wrapping code that calls Dispose for you):

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader()) {
    // do stuff with reader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few gotchas in the .net libraries. Stream is one, and the other is much of the Imaging API. These entities that use certain system resources don't garbage collect the attached system resources.

If anything uses the IDisposable API, the best thing to do is wrap it in a using block, as people have pointed out above.

Read up on "using", and keep it in mind whenever you're dealing with file handles or images.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the question has been answered but I do want to elaborate on one thing.

**Any time an object implements the `IDisposable` interface, you should dispose it** with the Dispose method or (even better) use the `using` statement.

If you are ever faced with this question in the future, just find out which interfaces it implements. Once you see `IDisposable` you know to dispose it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to clear the stream use null; Otherwise, use the Dispose(); method if your application no longer requires the use of the stream.

Comment: What does "clear the stream" mean, and what does setting a variable reference to null have to do with it?